# Hide modal not working after async fetch error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a process in my page that needs to fetch data from an API using `async` and `fetch`. while the data is being fetch, a loading modal is displayed and remove (using `$id.modal.('hide)`) after the data is fetched.

When the fetched correctly the data, the modal is removed without any problem. However if there is any sort of error while fetching the data (eg 404) the modal won't hide.

here is a link which simulates the problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tarounen/s4kf7b3L/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn-modal').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    getData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  });
  $('#btn-modal2').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    getData("https://jsonplaceholder404.typicode.com/todos/1");
  });

});

async function getData(url) {
  try {

    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (response.status != 200) {
      throw new Error(response);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    closeDialog();
  alert("got data");

  } catch (error) {
    closeDialog();
  alert("error");
  }
}

function closeDialog() {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">TEST.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="btn-modal" class="btn">VALID</button>
<button id="btn-modal2" class="btn">INVALID</button>
```

**UPDATE**

corrected the typo error in the simulation (there weren't typos the dev code) .. i will try to re simulate.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo. Call `closeDialog();` instead of `closeDialogue();` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo-error in `closeDialog()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn-modal').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    getData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  });
  $('#btn-modal2').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    getData("https://jsonplaceholder404.typicode.com/todos/1");
  });

});

async function getData(url) {
  try {

    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (response.status != 200) {
      throw new Error(response);
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    closeDialog();
  alert("got data");

  } catch (error) {
    closeDialog();
  alert("error");
  }
}

function closeDialog() {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">TEST.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="btn-modal" class="btn">VALID</button>
<button id="btn-modal2" class="btn">INVALID</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check your browser console, there is an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: closeDialogue is not defined
    at getData ((index):58)
```

Use the correct name.